# I want to replace the hello,'hi','gm' as 'greetings' and write the same to the text file

Tags: python

```
gre =['Hi','Hello','Hey','Whats up','Greetings','Hola','Good morning','Good afternoon','Good evening']
qus = []
quslist = db.questions.find({'date':{'$lt':dn, '$gt':dtr}})
for answers_record in quslist:
    qus.append(answers_record['questionText'])
    lis0 = [h.encode('utf-8') for h in qus]
    lis = ['greetings' if word in gre else word for word in lis0]
    print"day",lis
    thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')
    for item in lis:
        thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
    thefile.close()
```

I tried this

```
lis = ['greetings' if word in gre else word for word in lis0]
```

but I also need to replace the hello,`hi`,`gm` as `greetings` irrespective of case (like hi,hola) and write the same to the text file

Comment: What do you need exactly? I didn't understand !

Answer (score 0):

From your description you are searching some items in a list and trying to replace the some words each each of the items. however you code replace the whole item with the word. If this is the problem then I would recommend using [String.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) function as this will only replace the word and will not affect any strings that do not contain the words.